# $\lim (1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n = e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assuming the definition $e = \lim (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, I want to show that one also has $e = \lim (1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n.$ My idea was to try and squeeze $(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n$ between two sequences which we know converge to $e$, i.e., something like

$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{n-1} \leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n \leq \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n,$$

but the equality on the left sadly isn't true. Is there a way to adapt this idea into a working proof?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ (1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}=  (1+\frac{1}{n+1})^n(1+\frac{1}{n+1})$$

Now, you can use the product rule and you are done, or you can squeeze $(1+\frac{1}{n+1})$ between $1$ and something which converges to $1$ like... $(1+\frac{1}{n+1})$...

Comment: Simplicity is key! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{n+1}{n+2}\to\mathrm e\cdot1$$